# how to pass parameter in jsp in this case

Tags: java, jsp

I have DB structure like :

[image]

This is doGet() of Controller Servlet as :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    getSubjects(request, response);
}
```

and getSubjects(request, response) is :

```
private void getSubjects(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{
            try {
                    List<Subject> subjects = subjectDAO.subjectList();// I'm sending subjects List as Arttribute and, Please SEE *** below
                    ### HERE by passing subject ID Here.
                    List<Page> pages = pageDAO.topicList(subjectId); // Now I want to send pages List as Arttribute as well and, Please SEE### below
                    request.setAttribute("subjects", subjects);
                    request.setAttribute("pages", pages);
                    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp").forward(
                                    request, response);
            } catch (Exception e) {                        
                    throw new ServletException("Error ", e.getCause());
            }
    }
```

and this is my JSP

```
<ul class="subjects">    *** HERE below I'm getting that subjects List.
                        <c:forEach items="${subjects}" var="subject">
                          <li
                            <c:catch>
                              <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${subject.subjectId == param.subj_id}">
                                <c:out value=" class=\"selected\""/>
                                </c:when>
                              </c:choose>    
                            </c:catch>><a href='/contexct/super-controller?action=view-content&subj_id=
                           <c:out value="${subject.subjectId}"/>'>
                           <c:out value="${subject.subjectName}" />
                           </a></li>
                           <ul class="pages">
                            ### HERE below I can get that pages List .But how can I get value of subjectId So that I can get pages from DB, Please SEE$$$ above.
                            <c:forEach items="${pages}" var="page">
                                <li
                                  <c:catch>
                                     <c:choose>
                                        <c:when test="${page.pageId == param.topic_id}">
                                        <c:out value=" class=\"selected\""/>
                                       </c:when>
                                     </c:choose>    
                                   </c:catch>><a href='/contexct/super-controller?action=view-content&amp;topic_id=
                             <c:out value="${page.pageId}"/>'>
                             <c:out value="${page.pageName}" />
                           </a></li>
                         </c:forEach>
                       </ul>
                     </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
```

As I'm getting Subject data in jsp through :

```
<c:forEach items="${subjects}" var="subject">
```

Now how can I pass subject ids to this line in getSubjects():

```
 List<Page> pages = pageDAO.topicList(subjectId);
```

So that I can get pages corresponding to subject and set that list as :

```
 request.setAttribute("pages", pages);
```

Hope now you can understand my problem

#### UPDATE

I debugged in this way :

```
private void getSubjects(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{
    try {
        List<Subject> subjects = subjectDAO.subjectList();
        List<Page> pages = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < subjects.size(); i++) {
            pages = pageDAO.topicList(subjects.get(i).getSubjectId());
            System.out.println("List id is " + subjects.get(i).getSubjectId());
                            for (int i = 0; i < subjects.size(); i++) {
            pages = pageDAO.topicList(subjects.get(i).getSubjectId());
            System.out.println("List id is " + subjects.get(i).getSubjectId());
            for (int j = 0; j < pages.size(); j++) {                    
                System.out.println("Topics are " +pages.get(j).getTopicName());
            }
        }
        }
        request.setAttribute("subjects", subjects);
        request.setAttribute("pages", pages);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/content.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {             
        throw new ServletException("Cannot obtain subjects from DB", e.getCause());
    }
}
```

I got `Console` as :

```
List id is 1
Topics are App User Interface
List id is 2
Topics are Java Basics
Topics are OOP
List id is 3
List id is 4
```

which is correct, but could not be able to get this work

```
<c:forEach items="${pages}" var="page">
     <li
       <c:catch>
         <c:choose>
           <c:when test="${page.pageId == param.topic_id}">...
```

given above..

means nothing is returned there.

Comment: hello sorry what is your question?

Comment: When you are getting subjects, pass the first subject_id to fetch its pages on first load of page and then when changing subject pass subject_id back to action and fetch pages accordingly.

Comment: `request.getParameter("subj_id")` http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: As I earlier mentioned, send just first object's subject_id on initial,, as:
List<Subject> subjects = subjectDAO.subjectList();

List<Page> pages = pageDAO.topicList(subjects.get(0).getSubjectId());

Comment: String[] array =request.getParameterValues('subj_id'); convert that to list

Comment: @user3310291: thus you will be able to get pages of first subject.
When changing subject from view, set the request parameter and get in your changeListener and get pages of parameter accordingly.

Comment: @user3310291: Also, there is another way too. First get all subject and pages, then set a map of subject to pages list by cross iteration of two lists. Get the map on JSP and while iteration, access pages by key (subject_id).

Comment: @ParkashKumar will please provide me a code snap?

Comment: @user3310291: Okay, it ensures that you are getting subject list properly.
Check your pageDAO.topicList method's signature and parameter's data-type, does this method return List of pages and is String subjectId a proper argument for pageDAO.topicList?
Also check your log for exception occuring, it will be handy for you!

Comment: @ParkashKumar See my Latest Edit please

Comment: Okay, this is so annoying isn't it! huhhhhhhhhh, let me clear,, what do you really want to do?
How do you want to display your subjects and pages?
Will data be displayed at once or will single subject be displayed at a time with relevant pages and on changing subject the pages will be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I had to perform a similar task. 
I used a controller servlet. Then a database object that used classes to handle the retrieving of data from the data base. 
It doesn't appear that you are checking the "action" parameter being sent to the servlet.

```
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("getTopic")){
            int SubjectId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("SubjectId"));
            dao.getTopic(SubjectId);
            forward = "myjsp.jsp";
            request.setAttribute("subjects", dao.getAllSubjects());    
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listSubjects")){
            forward = "myjsp.jsp";
            request.setAttribute("categories", dao.getAllSubjects());

        } else {
            forward = "myjsp.jsp";
        }

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get pages from Map try following approach (Not Tested):

```
private void getSubjects(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException{

    try {
        List<Subject> subjects = subjectDAO.subjectList();
        List<Page> pages = null;
        Map<String, ArrayList<Page>> subjectPageMap = null;

        if(subjects!= null && subjects.size() > 0){
            subjectPageMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Page>>();
            for(Subject subject : subjects){
                pages = pageDAO.topicList(subject.getSubjectId());
                pages = pages != null && pages.size() > 0 ? pages : new ArrayList<Page>();
                subjectPageMap.put(subject.getSubjectId(), pages);
            }
        }

        request.setAttribute("subjects", subjects);
        request.setAttribute("subjectPageMap", subjectPageMap);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp").forward(
                                request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException("Error ", e.getCause());
    }
}
```

Comment: `Map<int, ArrayList<Page>> subjectPageMap = null;` gives error at `Map<int..`

Comment: what is datatype of your subjectId?

Comment: I typed that as `String`

Comment: Alas! still I'm not getting pages Man!

Comment: But why, if your method (pageDAO.topicList) is working fine for given subjectId, then it should populate Map. Try debugging your code and find the root of the issue.

Share exception, if you can't handle.

Comment: See My Latest Edit Please